# wait and change color in java

Tags: java, jframe, wait

I'm attempting to make my first game. It consists of two players moving around, trying to dodge yellow cubes. I have put in a few drops: Health, shield, coins. The Health adds health to the player who picks it up, and the coin adds score. But I'm having issues with the shield pickup.

I want the player who picks up the shield drop to turn cyan for 5 seconds and be invulnerable to all attacks from yellow cubes for the same amount of time.

Here's some of my code:

```
package com.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Player extends GameObject {    

Color one = Color.white;
Color two = Color.red;
Random r = new Random();
Handler handler;

public Player(int x, int y, ID id, Handler handler) {
    super(x, y, id);
    this.handler = handler;     

}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 50);
}

public void tick() throws InterruptedException{
    int a = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
    Color c = Color.white;
    switch (a){
    case(1): c = Color.red;
        break;
    case(2): c = Color.green;
        break;
    case(3): c = Color.blue;
        break;          

    }

    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    x = Game.clamp(x, 0, Game.WIDTH - 56);
    y = Game.clamp(y, 0, Game.HEIGHT - 79);


    /*
    if(speedBoost = 1){

    }
    */
    if(HUD.scoreOne == 1){
        handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, c, 50, 50, 0.04f, handler));
    }


    collision(handler, null);
}

private void collision(Handler handler, Graphics g) throws InterruptedException{

    this.handler = handler;

    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Enemy){

            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

                if(id == ID.Player){
                    HUD.HEALTHone -= 2;

                }
                if(id == ID.Player2){
                    HUD.HEALTHtwo -= 2;
                }
                if(HUD.HEALTHone == 0 || HUD.HEALTHtwo == 0){

                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.HealthPickup){

            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

                if(id == ID.Player){
                    HUD.HEALTHone += 15;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);
                }
                if(id == ID.Player2){
                    HUD.HEALTHtwo += 15;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);

                }
            }
        }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Coin){

            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

                if(id == ID.Player){
                    HUD.scoreOne += 1;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);
                }
                if(id == ID.Player2){
                    HUD.scoreTwo += 1;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);

                }
            }
        }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.ShieldPickup){

            if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

                if(id == ID.Player){
                    one = Color.cyan;
                    HUD.HEALTHone += 15;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);
                }
                if(id == ID.Player2){
                    two = Color.cyan;
                    for(int j = 0; j < 2;j++){
                    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            changeBackTwoColor();
                        }
                    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                }   

                    HUD.HEALTHtwo += 15;
                    handler.removeObject(tempObject);

                }
            }

        }
    }


public void changeBackOneColor(){
    one = Color.white;
}


public void changeBackTwoColor(){
    two = Color.red;
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    if(id == ID.Player) g.setColor(one);
    //if(id == ID.Player2) g.setColor(two);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

}

Here's just the collision method if that's easier to look at:

```
private void collision(Handler handler, Graphics g) throws InterruptedException{

this.handler = handler;

for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
    GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

    if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Enemy){

        if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

            if(id == ID.Player){
                HUD.HEALTHone -= 2;

            }
            if(id == ID.Player2){
                HUD.HEALTHtwo -= 2;
            }
            if(HUD.HEALTHone == 0 || HUD.HEALTHtwo == 0){

                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.HealthPickup){

        if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

            if(id == ID.Player){
                HUD.HEALTHone += 15;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
            if(id == ID.Player2){
                HUD.HEALTHtwo += 15;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);

            }
        }
    }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Coin){

        if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

            if(id == ID.Player){
                HUD.scoreOne += 1;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
            if(id == ID.Player2){
                HUD.scoreTwo += 1;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);

            }
        }
    }else if(tempObject.getID() == ID.ShieldPickup){

        if(getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())){

            if(id == ID.Player){
                one = Color.cyan;
                HUD.HEALTHone += 15;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
            if(id == ID.Player2){
                two = Color.cyan;
                for(int j = 0; j < 2;j++){
                final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
                executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        changeBackTwoColor();
                    }
                }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            }   

                HUD.HEALTHtwo += 15;
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use a Swing Timer

Answer (score 0):

At the collision with an enemy you are not checking if you are in "cyan" mode.
try something like this:

```
 if(tempObject.getID() == ID.Enemy && ((id == ID.Player && !one.equals(Color.cyan) || (id == ID.Player2 && !two.equals(Color.cyan))){
```

Comment: Okay.  Thank you. How do I make the effect only last for 5 seconds?

Comment: @NickBray, I already told you the tool to use. Please look up and go through the tutorial